# Lombok + Java 13 module + NetBeans 11 + Maven

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, lombok

All right,

I am trying to get lombok to work on a maven project with NetBeans 11 + JdK 13. The IDE seems to see the lombok and it autocompletes on @Getter annotated methods but at compile time lombok looks like it is not there

on my pom:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.10</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-alpha1</version>
    </dependency>
```

module-info

```
module uno.anahata.rpc {
    requires static org.slf4j;
    requires static lombok;
    requires org.apache.commons.lang3;    
}
```

compiler output

```
-d C:\Users\Pablo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\anahata-rpc\target\classes -classpath C:\Users\Pablo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\anahata-rpc\target\classes; --module-path C:\Users\Pablo\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.10\lombok-1.18.10.jar;C:\Users\Pablo\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.0-alpha1\slf4j-api-2.0.0-alpha1.jar;C:\Users\Pablo\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.9\commons-lang3-3.9.jar; -sourcepath C:\Users\Pablo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\anahata-rpc\src\main\java;C:\Users\Pablo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\anahata-rpc\target\generated-sources\annotations; -s C:\Users\Pablo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\anahata-rpc\target\generated-sources\annotations -g -deprecation -target 13 -source 13 --module-version 13.0.0-SNAPSHOT
File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
incrementalBuildHelper#beforeRebuildExecution
Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\Pablo\Documents\NetBeansProjects\anahata-rpc\target\classes
incrementalBuildHelper#afterRebuildExecution
-------------------------------------------------------------
COMPILATION ERROR : 
-------------------------------------------------------------
uno/anahata/rpc/client/RpcInvocationHandler.java:[54,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable log
  location: class uno.anahata.rpc.client.RpcInvocationHandler
uno/anahata/rpc/client/RpcInvocationHandler.java:[68,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable log
  location: class uno.anahata.rpc.client.RpcInvocationHandler
2 errors
```

Comment: I would guess you need `requires static lombok;` in the module-info file (if your code is modular).

Comment: Tried that, also added the dependency to the maven project with provided scope, the NetBeans editor seems to pick it up buy at compile time, the compiler shows compilation errors

Comment: Did you try setting lombok to the default compile scope?

Comment: Yes, tried that, didn't work

Comment: The compiler complains only about missing `log` fields, not about getters. Do you have a `@Slf4j` annotation on the `RpcInvocationHandler` class?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try moving the lombok dependy inside annotationProcessorPaths and do clean build

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.10</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Yes, that was it https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2325

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the Netbeans annotation processors for Lombok
https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/annotations-lombok.html
?

Comment: That is for non-maven projects (nb nuild)

Comment: @pranahata maybe I'm wrong, but I had a similar problem in IntelliJ IDEA. The root cause was disabled annotations processors. The error message was exactly the same.